# Python payroll program looping error

Tags: python

I have this program I'm trying to write and I can't get it to stop asking the input over and over. Where is my error? Any help will do; I'm new at programming so this is all foreign.

```
def main():
    hours,rate = getinput()
    strtime,overtimehr,overtime = calculate_hours(hours)
    regular,overtime,totalpay  = calculate_pay(regular,overtimehr,rate)


def getinput():
    print ()
    print ('How many hours were worked?')
    print ('Hours worked must be at least 8 and no more than 86.')
    hours = float(input('Now enter the hours worked please:'))

    while hours < 8 or hours > 86: #validate the hours
        print ('Error--- The hours worked must be atleast 8 and no more than 86.')
        hours = float(input('Please try again:'))

    print ('What is the pay rate?')
    print ('The pay rate must be at least $7.00 and not more than $50.00.')
    rate = float(input('Now enter the pay rate:'))

    while rate < 7 or rate > 50: #validate the payrate
        print ('Error--- The pay rate must be at least $7.00 and not more than $50.00.')
        rate = float (input('Please try again:'))

        return hours, rate

    getinput()

def calculate_hours(hours):
    if hours < 40:
        strtime = hours
        overtime = 0
    else:
        strtime = 40
    overtimehr = hours - 40

    if hours > 40:
        overtimerate = 1.5 * rate
        overtime = (hours-40) * overtimerate
        hours = 40
    else:
        overtime = 0

    return strtime, overtime, overtimehr

    calculate_hours(hours)

def calculate_payregular(regular,totalpay,rate):
    regular = hours * rate
    totalpay = overtime + regular

    return regular, totalpay,rate

    calculate_payregular(regular,totalpay,rate)


def calprint (rate, strtime, overtimehr, regular, overtime, totalpay):
    print ("           Payroll Information")
    print ()
    print ("Pay rate                $", format (rate,  '9,.2f'))
    print ("Regular Hours            ", format (strtime,  '9,.2f'))
    print ("Overtime hours           ", format (overtimehr,  '9,.2f'))
    print ("Regular pay             $", format (regular,  '9.2f'))
    print ("Overtime pay            $", format (overtime,  '9.2f'))
    print ("Total Pay               $", format (totalpay,  '9.2f'))

    calprint (rate, strtime, overtimehr, regular, overtime, totalpay)

main ()
```

Answer (score 1):

All your functions, including `getinput()`, appear to be calling themselves at the end, which is probably the cause of your problem. You don't need that last line in any of your functions - I'm not sure why you think you do. Remove it from all of them.

Also I expect `return hours, rate` should be un-indented one level.

Comment: Thank you very much that helped and i saw a few other errors that needed fixing.